# Vue.js code doesn't work on a html without cdn

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm new to Vue.js and i have a header html which doesn't have cdn link of Vue.js.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <div class="containerNav">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/logo.png" height="30"/></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="login.html">TestPage</a>
                        </li>                       
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-5" id="login-App">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav float-right">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">{{data.user}}</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" onclick="cleanLocalStorage()" href="login.html">Log out</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I load this header html with jquery document.ready function.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".footer").load("./footer.html");
    $(".header").load("./header.html");       
});
```

Thererefore i cant show Vue.js variable on the page. Here is my Vue.js code

```
var loginApp = new Vue({
    el: '#login-App',
    data: function () {
        return {
            data: {}
        }
    },
    methods: {
        fetchData: function () {
            Vue.set(loginApp.data, 'user', JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')).name);
        }
    }
});
```

If i use cdn link on header html, it works, but i prefer to use only on index page. Is there any trick for this situation? Should i use Vue.js CLI instead of cdn?

Comment: Why use jQuery and `.load()` when you could make those vue components and just include them through vue?

Comment: @Xander Luciano i din't know that. Is that Vue.js template what you point out?

Comment: Oh dude! You'll love this. You can create "template files" in vue called single file components: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html and say you name it `mysite-header` you can then use that as a component and on your mainpage you can just do `<mysite-header>` and it'll just load that whole template in.

Comment: I'll type up an answer with some details on how to do that. Should make things a lot easier for you.

Comment: Thanx. I used handlebars templates always and loaded with jquery. Vue.js is new for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try using [Single File Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html) to load in the header and footer as components in vue.

*Note: I'm using Babel and ES6 because it has some great features.*

So here's your main javascript file, call it `main.js` or something

```
// Import Vue and Vue Components
import Vue from 'vue'
import mysite-header from './components/mysite-header.vue'
import mysite-footer from './components/mysite-footer.vue'

// Setup Vue
let app = new Vue({
    el:'#mysite-app',
    data: {
        pagename: "This can be a variable",
    },
    components: {
        mysite-header,
        mysite-footer,
    },
});
```

Now we build up the HTML for this page:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Normal HTML Stuff here -->
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="mysite-app">
            <mysite-header>
            </mysite-header>

            <!-- Static html content, or another vue template-->

            <mysite-footer>
            </mysite-footer>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now when vue is loaded, it'll automatically replace the custom html tags with your template files located at `./components/mysite-header.vue` and `./components/mysite-footer.vue`

Example of mysite-header.vue:

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-block">
                        <h4 class="card-title">{{ titleText }}</h4>
                        <hr class="my-2">
                        <p class="card-text">
                            <slot></slot>
                        </p>
                        <p>Body Text: {{ bodyText }}</p>
                        <input v-model="titleText">
                        <button :title="titleText">Hover over me!</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        // There are properties we pass from the parent
        props: ['initTitleText','bodyText'],
        data() {
            // We can set local data equal to a property from the parent
            // To create a "default" value that isn't bound to the parent's value
            return {
                titleText: this.initTitleText
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            // Called when this vue is first loaded
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>

<style>
    .card {
        margin: .5rem 0;
    }
</style>
```

There's a lot more to it of course, but really the best way to figure this out is to just slowly build up and try passing more and more data and see how things interact and how things are bound together etc. Overall I think you'll find yourself using vue more than jQuery.